# association of posts in wordpress for query - two questions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, post

I am a beginning web developer building my website idea in wordpress. In my website I am planning on having two custom post types, call then type A and type B. I would like, for a user to be able to query all the type A posts that are associated with a specific type B post and the reverse as well (all the type B posts that are associated with a specific type A post). So, I guess my first question is what should my approach be to do this? Should I be using categories, custom taxonomies, just storing some array of meta information in each post detailing which posts of the other type are associated with it, or some other approach?

My second question is how to go about querying this information and then displaying it to the user. I mean, I realize this is kind of a simple question but how is this generally done? Are all the posts queried and sorted on the server in php and then passed to the client machine? If so, does one have to run some javascript to display the first 5 results on page 1, the second 5 on page 2 and so on? Or, are each 5 results queried in batches as needed?

I realize this question may be kind of vague/naive. I am just beginning. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off looking at registering a taxonomy and then adding that taxonomy to each of your CPT when you create them. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

The second part of your question can get complex quickly. If you just want to show all the posts that share the taxonomy, then you can create a `taxonomy-term.php` template.

Beyond that, I think you really need to look over the WP documentation. It sounds like there are some concepts that you are lacking that would be answered by spending some time there.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

It's a PHP CMS, so, yes, the essentials all happen on the server. The url path gives a lot of the query instructions, and you can also build out your own queries using the WP APIs.

Also look at one of WordPress' own themes for example code in addition to what's on the Codex. That can really help get a feel for how the platform works. I say that because you say you are a beginner - looking at and playing with well formed code can be super helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't agree on the first part - if I got the question right :) It seems to me that the question involves having different connections between any post from type A to type B, it seems better to keep a meta than to create a new tax for each connection between them [if the question is about MANY different connections and not few connections between MANY posts] The rest is really great info and the resources should be enough to get bob going! :)

Comment: ok, thanks guys. Yeah, I would like to have connections between any one type A and many type B's or any one type B and many type A's.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. Can you give a more concrete example? If I had a use case I might be able to come up with a better answer. I was thinking if type a were movies and type b were books than you might want a movie post that is a mystery to also show books that were mystery. But sounds like you want something else